# sharing session between WARs

Tags: session, jsf, servlets

Is it possible for the session data of one war file to be shared by other war file

Comment: I just realized I answered this question to you a few hours ago.. You can edit your questions, no need to create new ones.

Answer (score 3):

To the point, you just need to configure the server somehow to store the session in a cookie without a path. In case of Tomcat, you can just set `emptySessionPath` attribute of the `<Connector>` element to `true` in `/conf/server.xml`. Also see [this Tomcat Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html).

```
<Connector ... emptySessionPath="true">
```

This however affects *all* webbaps deployed on the same server.

**Update**: as you are actually using Websphere (which uses Tomcat under the hoods), you need to alter the Tomcat connector in Websphere's `config.xml` to include the following attribute:

```
<attribute name="emptySessionPath">true</attribute>
```

Comment: I am using websphere. the reason I want to do it is to share login information across multiple web application

Answer (score 2):

Its not easy to do.  but I have been able to do this using tomcat.  Here is a link http://www.fwd.at/tomcat/sharing-session-data-howto.html I'm not sure what server you are using though.  Also, why do you need to do this, there may another solution depending on what you need to do.

Comment: I am using websphere. the reason I want to do it is to share login information across multiple web application

Comment: An easier way (and probably safer) would be to store the information you need in a database that all webapps could reference

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat has the [Signle-Sign-On Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Single%20Sign%20On%20Valve):

> The Single Sign On Vale is utilized when you wish to give users the ability to sign on to any one of the web applications associated with your virtual host, and then have their identity recognized by all other web applications on the same virtual host.

You may also try to implement [single-sign-on using cookies](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:myREu31MRrEJ:ce.sejong.ac.kr/~shindk/031_gia/xml/IEEE/SSO/Single%2520sign-on%2520using%2520cookies%2520for%2520Web%2520applications.pdf+single-sign-on+cookies&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESh0wTJ-jyKw5PylqMrU_pkXSA_4P0kH9Oofg1N4bASIezGxmZ2oQpK-WuUpToVJqUiXoADm0yPhcQDfU5Vj4T0F-mLlNbXyeRbz6E9M1QtXHC9kBKOYK_FvEZiCVTk5b8b8323Z&sig=AHIEtbS737Vy4MnieO3mSZManKESOfe1XQ) (though this has security drawbacks).

Comment: The link here appears to be broken. It might also be useful to explain what the security drawbacks are.