# What are common technical problems when splitting one Java EE application into multiple war files?

Tags: web-applications, jakarta-ee, war

I read a lot about problems when deploying one Java EE application as multiple WAR files. For instance, I know that [each WAR has its own session context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2477845) and therefore keeping state is a little bit tricky. And that there are [organizational disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3906881) when using exploded WARs.

But to make a mature decision about splitting an application or not, knowledge of all technical disadventages would be helpful. Could you list them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in addition to the 2 reasons you have already mentioned.

1. When you have an application deployed as 1 EAR with multiple WARs in it then you would have let all the jar's loaded at the ear classloader level to get rid of all the classpath headaches. As soon as you decided to split them into their own deployable artifacts, then you need to bring up all those jars in each of the war files.
2. The security context, transaction context might not have been the issue earlier as everything was co-located. this is also something you might have to take into consideration if this is applicable.